# Translating server file paths to URLs in Codeigniter

Tags: url, codeigniter, path

I'm developing my first application in Codeigniter 2.0.2, and I've got a minor issue I can't seem to find any info about on the web.

The application revolves around resources stored locally on the server (namely images and audio files) which need to be exposed to the user. The locations of these resources are stored in a DB as absolute paths. As a result, I find myself needing to translate server paths to base_url-based URLs fairly often.

I already wrote a simple and robust-enough function to handle it for me, but with all the seemingly-relevant helpers in CI (url, path), I can't shake the feeling that I just reinvented the wheel.

At the least, I would think there would be some kind of CI function (say, "basify") that will translate any server path to a base_url-relative path like so:

```
$server_path = '/server/path/to/app/resources/image.jpg';
basify( $server_path );  // returns 'resources/image.jpg' or './resources/image.jpg'
```

where the CI app lives in /server/path/to/app. Then it's a simple call to base_url() to make the URL.

Does anything like that exist?

Edit: And yes, I know that a simple preg_replace will handle most cases for me (at least those where the resource is within the base path), but I feel like this should be CI's job, not mine! Half the reason I'm using it is because I don't want to think about path management.

Comment: I don't think there is anything in CI that will do this for you so extending one of the helpers like you have already done is probably your best bet.  Make sure to look at the file helper if you are displaying file information to your users.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use php function `str_replace` together with codeigniter `FCPATH` constant.
Your code will be:

```
function basify($image_path) {
    return str_replace(FCPATH, '', $image_path);
}
```

The `FCPATH` constant is new to me, but I have done some tests and it works fine.

Comment: Yeah, that's one way to achieve it, but it only works with absolute paths that are a subdirectory of FCPATH. I could assume all relative paths are relative to FCPATH, and then assert any absolute path must be under FCPATH (which is probably good design anyway), but those are the kinds of decisions I'd expect CI to standardize via a helper.